# Показать баланс перевода etherscan

Tags: javascript, ethereum

Есть скрипт, он показывает сколько этериума было переданно в сумме с адреса юзера на мой смарт контракт. Если смарт контракт написал в мейн сети, то все стабильно выводится, но если контракт написан в тестовой сети ропстен, то информации нет, как будто транзакции отсутствуют. Вот сам скрипт:

```
function getInfo(initialInfo){
    var rate = fetch("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/")
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        });
    var defLastBlock = 0;
    if(!initialInfo)
        initialInfo = {sum: 0, timesum: 0, num: 0, investors: {}, dates: [], nums: [], sums: [], min: -1, max: 0};

    var jsonInternalPromise = fetch("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&address=0x4f3db6d4c97b8248ad5e244e4f619086084f6848&startblock=" + ((initialInfo.lastBlockInner || initialInfo.lastBlock || defLastBlock) + 1) + "&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken")
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        });

    return fetch("https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x4f3db6d4c97b8248ad5e244e4f619086084f6848&startblock=" + ((initialInfo.lastBlock || defLastBlock) + 1) + "&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken")
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(json){
            var info = json.result.reduce(function(info, tr){
                var val = +tr.value;
                if(!info.firstBlock){
                    info.firstBlock = +tr.blockNumber;
                    info.firstTime = +tr.timeStamp;
                }
                info.lastBlock = +tr.blockNumber;
                info.lastTime = +tr.timeStamp;

                if(info.investors[tr.from]){
                    info.investors[tr.from].gas += tr.gasUsed * tr.gasPrice;
                }else{
                    info.investors[tr.from] = {
                        sum: 0,
                        inv: [],
                        gas: tr.gasUsed * tr.gasPrice
                    }
                }

                if(+tr.isError)
                    return info;

                if(val){
                    info.last = val;
                    info.last_time = tr.timeStamp * 1000;

                    info.sum += val;
                    info.timesum += val*tr.blockNumber;

                    var inv = info.investors[tr.from];
                    if(!inv.sum)
                        info.num += 1;

                    inv.sum += val;
                    inv.inv.push({
                        sum: val,
                        time: info.last_time
                    });

                    var investment = info.investors[tr.from].sum;

                    info.dates.push(info.last_time);
                    info.nums.push(info.num);
                    info.sums.push(Math.round(info.sum/Math.pow(10,16))/100);

                    if(info.min == -1 || info.min > investment)
                        info.min = investment;
                    if(investment > info.max)
                        info.max = investment;
                }
                return info;
            }, initialInfo);

            info.avg = info.sum/info.num;

            return rate.then(function(ratejson){
                info.rate = +ratejson[0].price_usd;
                info.sum_usd = info.sum/Math.pow(10, 18) * info.rate;

                return jsonInternalPromise.then(function(json){
                    info = json.result.reduce(function(info, tr){
                        if(!(+tr.isError)){
                            var inv = info.investors[tr.to];
                            if(inv){
                                inv.got = (inv.got || 0) + (+tr.value);
                                inv.gotTime = tr.timeStamp*1000;
                            }
                            info.got = (info.got || 0) + (+tr.value);
                        }
                        info.lastBlockInner = +tr.blockNumber;
                        info.lastTimeInner = +tr.timeStamp;
                        return info;
                    }, info);
                    return info;
                }, function(e){
                    console.log('Error fetching internal transactions: ' + e);
                    return info;
                });
            });

        });
}

function drawChart(info){
    if (document.getElementById('chart-container2')) {
        var avg = (Math.round(info.avg/Math.pow(10,16))/100);
        var min = (Math.ceil(info.min/Math.pow(10,16))/100);
        var max = (Math.round(info.max/Math.pow(10,16))/100);
        Highcharts.chart('chart-container2', {
            /*tooltip: {
              /*  formatter: function () {

                    if (this.series.name == 'AVG') {
                        return '<b>' + this.key + '</b><br/>';
                    } else {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            new Date(this.x) + ': ' + this.y;
                    }
                }
            }, */
            title: {
                text: 'Combination chart',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'white'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                    day: '%e %b',
                    week: '%e %b',
                    month: '%e %b',
                    year: '%e %b'
                },
                title: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            labels: {
                items: [{
                    html: 'Average ' + avg + 'ETH, max ' + max + ' ETH',
                    style: {
                        left: '50px',
                        top: '18px',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'white'
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#A0A0A0'
                },
                itemHoverStyle: {
                    color: '#FFF'
                },
                itemHiddenStyle: {
                    color: '#444'
                }
            },
            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                title: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                minorGridLineWidth: 0.2,
                gridLineWidth: 0.1,
                alternateGridColor: null,
            }],

            plotOptions: {
                column: {},
                spline: {
                    dashStyle: 'Dot',
                    marker: {enabled: false},
                    states: {hover: {enabled: true}},
                },
                area: {
                    marker: {enabled: false},
                    states: {hover: {enabled: true}},
                    style: 'dotted',
                    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                },
                pie: {}

            },

            series: [
                { //Line
                    type: 'area',
                    name: 'ETH',

                    data: info.sums.map(function(e, i) { return [info.dates[i], e] }),
                    marker: {
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                        fillColor: 'white'
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: true,

                    color: '#ee06a4',
                    shadow: {
                        color: '#ee06a4',
                        width: 3,
                        offsetX: 0,
                        offsetY: 0
                    }
                }, { // Line 2
                    type: 'spline',
                    name: 'Users',
                    data: info.nums.map(function(e, i) { return [info.dates[i], e] }),
                    color: '#78ee06',
                    enableMouseTracking: true,
                    shadow: {
                        color: '#78ee06',
                        width: 3,
                        offsetX: 0,
                        offsetY: 0
                    },
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value;
                    }
                },
                {
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Investment',
                    data: [
                        {
                            name: avg + ' AVG',
                            sliced: true,
                            selected: true,
                            y: avg,
                            color: 'rgba(150,100,50,0.1)' // AVG color
                        }, {
                            name: min + ' MIN',
                            y: min,
                            color: 'rgba(200,122,200,0.7)' // Joe's color
                        },
                        {
                            name: max + ' MAX',
                            y: max,
                            color: 'rgba(200,122,200,1)' // John's color
                        },
                    ],
                    center: [100, 80],
                    size: 100,
                    showInLegend: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }]
        });
    }

}

function findAddress(address){
    var addr = address.toLowerCase();
    if(!window.investmentInfo)
        return null;

    if(investmentInfo.investors[addr])
        return addr;

    for(var key in investmentInfo.investors){
        if(key.indexOf(addr) === 0)
            return key;
    }

    return null;
}

function updateDividentsTimer(investmentInfo, addr){
    if(investmentInfo)
        updateDividents(investmentInfo, addr);
    else
        setCalcValues('?', '?', '?', '?', '?');
}

function updateDividents(investmentInfo, addr){
    var currentPs = window.multiplier.methods.currentReceiverIndex().call();
    var countsPs = window.multiplier.methods.getDeposits(addr).call();
    var count = '-';

    var got = ((investmentInfo.got || 0)/Math.pow(10,18)).toFixed(8).replace(/(\.[^0]*)0+$/, '$1');
    var gas = ((investmentInfo.gas || 0)/Math.pow(10,18)).toFixed(8);
    var sum = (investmentInfo.sum/Math.pow(10, 18)).toFixed(8).replace(/(\.[^0]*)0+$/, '$1');
    var count_all = (investmentInfo.inv.length);
    var lastPayout = '&mdash;';
    if(investmentInfo.gotTime){
        let d = new Date(investmentInfo.gotTime);
        lastPayout = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
            d.getFullYear() + " " + ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    }

    setCalcValues(count, count_all, sum, got, lastPayout);

    Promise.all([currentPs, countsPs]).then(function(vals){
        var counts = vals[1];
        if (counts.idxs.length > 0) {
            count = +counts.idxs[0] - vals[0];
            setCalcValues(count);
        }
    });
}

function calcInvestment(resetTime){
    if(!updateDividentsTimer.startTime)
        updateDividentsTimer.startTime = +new Date();

    var inp = document.getElementById('inputInvestments');
    var text = inp.value.trim().replace(/,/g, '.');
    if(/^0x[\da-f]*$/i.test(text)){
        updateDividentsTimer.timeDiff = Math.max(window.investmentInfo.last_time - (+new Date()), 0);
        //Address
        var addr = findAddress(text);
        var info;
        if(addr){
            info = window.investmentInfo.investors[addr];
            localStorage.setItem('address', addr);
            if(text.length < addr.length){
                inp.value = addr;
                createSelection(inp, text.length, addr.length);
            }
        }
        updateDividentsTimer(info, addr);
    }else{
        updateDividentsTimer(null);
    }


}

function setCalcValues(count, count_all, inv, got, lastPayout){
    if(typeof(count) !== 'undefined')
        document.getElementById('calcDepCountInQueue').innerHTML = count;
    if(typeof(inv) !== 'undefined')
        document.getElementById('calcInvestmentValue').innerHTML = inv;
    if(typeof(got) !== 'undefined')
        document.getElementById('calcDividendsOut').innerHTML = got;
    if(typeof(lastPayout) !== 'undefined')
        document.getElementById('calcLastPayout').innerHTML = lastPayout;
    if(typeof(count_all) !== 'undefined')
        document.getElementById('calcDepCount').innerHTML = count_all;
}

function createSelection(field, start, end) {
    if( field.createTextRange ) {
        var selRange = field.createTextRange();
        selRange.collapse(true);
        selRange.moveStart('character', start);
        selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
        selRange.select();
    } else if( field.setSelectionRange ) {
        field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
    } else if( field.selectionStart ) {
        field.selectionStart = start;
        field.selectionEnd = end;
    }
    field.focus();
}       

function onChangeLang(lang){
    localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
    return true;
}

function getContractInstance(){
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/metamask"));
    var abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"MULTIPLIER","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"currentReceiverIndex","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"depositor","type":"address"}],"name":"getDeposits","outputs":[{"name":"idxs","type":"uint256[]"},{"name":"deposits","type":"uint128[]"},{"name":"expects","type":"uint128[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"idx","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getDeposit","outputs":[{"name":"depositor","type":"address"},{"name":"deposit","type":"uint256"},{"name":"expect","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getQueueLength","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"PROMO_PERCENT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"depositor","type":"address"}],"name":"getDepositsCount","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"}]');
    var address = '0x4f3db6d4c97b8248ad5e244e4f619086084f6848';
    var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

    return contractInstance;
}
```

Сейчас стоят настройки такие `var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/metamask"));` т.е основная сеть  и контракт написанный в основной сети 0x4f3db6d4c97b8248ad5e244e4f619086084f6848. Но если я меняю адрес на 0xd18a35E0a7669404dCF3a5ADf78907ab3F0Aab17(написан в ропстене) и меняю сеть в переменной web3 на https://ropsten.infura.io/metamask, то баланс не отображается, хотя если смотреть по блокам https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&address=0xd18a35E0a7669404dCF3a5ADf78907ab3F0Aab17&startblock, то видно что транзакции есть

Comment: слишком много  текста..вряд ли кто-то будет это читать

Comment: @СергейПетрашко суть в том, что скрипт рабоатет не для всех адресов